# Add local user with administrator rights and to be disabled in a week

Tags: command-line, windows-10, user-accounts

I am preparing my pc lab for a workshop which will take two days.

I have been told to create local administrator accounts for each computer.

It is possible to add a user "workshop" with password "123456" usin NET command.

```
net user workshop 123456 /add
net localgroup "Administrators" "workshop" /add
```

But I need more. I need the user should be disabled after three days. What should be the command line like?

Comment: It's your lab PC, why cant you just log-in after three days and disable the accounts?

Comment: Bear in mind even if there *is* a way, they could easily undo that, create another account, get in to your main account etc. I'm not sure it would stop much.

Comment: @Jonno, thank you for your advise. The guests will not harm the computer I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done step by step:

1) Create user:

```
net user workshop 123456 /add
```

2) Add user to "Administrators" group:

```
net localgroup "Administrators" "workshop" /add
```

3) Set expiration date:

```
net user workshop /expires:27.02.2016
```

This looks OK.

Comment: Just remember, by making them admin, they can change their expiration time for workstation accounts.

Comment: @FrankThomas you are right. Maybe I should change the group. More powerful than limited user, but less authorized than administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the Task Scheduler for this

1. Create a batch file with the command to delete the corresponding user  using net user(net user usrname /del)
2. goto task scheduler select  create a new task
3. choose approiate trigger
4. Under action tab select start a program
5. be sure to check to check "run with highest privillage(after creating task)"

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to disable an account on a schedule, but all are potentially vulnerable to tampering by an administrative account, when applied to local (workgroup) accounts.

For a workgroup you can use the `net user workshop /expires:mm/dd/yyyy` to automatically expire the account. Alternately you can create a Scheduled Task on the workstation, which runs [`net user workshop /active:no`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) 
You can automate the creation of the scheduled task using [`schtasks.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)  .
The problem with this approach is that the administrative user could remove the scheduled task, or change their expiration date. There is basically nothing you can do to prevent a local admin from accessing local resources, so for workgroups, there is no perfect answer.

For a domain user, you can go a little further because you can seperate local admin rights from domain admin rights. In that case, if the user is not delegated user management, then you can just use `/expires:MM/DD/YYYY` on the domain account. If the user is delegated user management, but is not able to access the domain controller, you can schedule a task there to disable the user.